# How to do a row count in VBA to see if I need to pull down a calculation?

Tags: vba, excel

I am about as new to VBA in Excel as you get... I'm now looking at a Macro that is having some issues with calculations when only one row of data is returned (it's causing all proceeding rows to populate either an N/A or a #REF because the calculation is getting dragged down)

Esentially what I'm looking to do is use some sort of **IF statement with a row count to determine if the calculation should be brought down or not.**

Currently, the code reads as follows:

```
Range("I7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=0,0,(RC[-1]/RC[-2])*10000)"
Range("I7").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I8").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

What I think I need to do is anything with a rowcount less than 1 would not get pulled down, else pull the column down.

Am I approaching this the right way? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: It appears you haven't accepted answers to any of your questions. You're likely to get better answers from people if you recognize them when they help you. You accept an answer by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the rowcount. I think you just need to have the formula applied to all cells in column I starting in row 7 down to the last populated row. In my example I'm checking for the last row in column H.

Here is how you do that:

```
Sub AddFormulaToColumn()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = Range("H" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("I7:I" & lastRow)
    rng.Formula = "=IF(RC[-2]=0,0,(RC[-1]/RC[-2])*10000)"
End Sub
```

You can modify this by changing the ws definition to the sheet you want to work with, and if the last row is in a column other than "H", modify that as well.

Comment: Thanks very much! I haven't checked to see if this worked as I actually was able to get mine up and running -- but this is very helpful.